# Could not get rid of Error inflating class fragment error

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to show some points in google map in my app. So I tryed the code below to achieve this:

```
public class MessageDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_details);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Long latitude   = getIntent().getLongExtra("latitude",0);
        Long longtitude = getIntent().getLongExtra("longtitude", 0);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longtitude)).title("Marker"));
    }

}
```

And here is my  activity_message_details.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datetime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googleMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I got `Error inflating class fragment` error in the setContectView part. I know similar questions are asked many times, I checked out all of the topics about this in stackoverflow, but could not get rid of it.

There is one more thing. Can I show the map with marker in a pop up instead of opening new activity. And I also need to add some textviews to pop up. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

 if (mMap == null) {
        mMapFragment= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                      .findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        mMap =  mMapFragment.getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should I add this?

Comment: Replace your SupportMapFragment implementation after oncreate with it.

Comment: But it gives error in setContentView part? Program does not even came to there

Comment: Can you make your explanation clearer? Or post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my problem was about API key. After adding an API key to manifest file, outside of application tags it solved:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyCv0EKZ7WxirSW0V-lrUI6zKt-8hl5QwRU" />
```